# How to preg_replace this pattern: <!--[if gte mso 9]&gt;-->

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

How do I `preg_replace` this pattern: `<!--[if gte mso 9]&gt;-->`

This is my full code:

```
$content = preg_replace("/<!--[if gte mso 9]&gt;-->/", "", $content);
```

Comment: first: learn basic regex syntax. You've got multiple regex metacharacters in there, preventing them from being seen as part of the pattern, e.g. `[`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square brackets have a special meaning in regular expressions, so you need to escape them:

`$content = preg_replace("/<!--\[if gte mso 9\]&gt;-->/", "", $content);`

*NB: as you are doing a simple replace without regex, this will be faster:*

`` `$content = str_replace("<!--[if gte mso 9]&gt;-->", "", $content); ``

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why I should use str_replace and how it is faster? Can I use this for other instances, like preg_replace("/&nbsp;/" and preg_replace("/<h2><\/h2>/"?

Comment: `str_replace` simply takes the given string, searches for it and replaces it. `preg_replace` treats the string as a regular expression which is far more powerful. Regular expressions can do things like: `/I have [0-9]* apples?/` which matches `I have 1 apple`, `I have 2 apples`, etc... (that's just one example out of the loads of things regex can do). But as it's more powerful it takes longer to parse and figure out. Hope that's clearer, feel free to ask if not :) x

Comment: Got it, great reply. One final question, is it possible to add the above pre_replace examples into one line? Instead of running then separately? I am referring to preg_replace("/&nbsp;/" and preg_replace("/<h2><\/h2>/"?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I forgot to answer about those. Yep you can for the space: `str_replace('&nbsp;', ...`. For the h2 one, it depends if you are trying to match text that is surrounded by `<h2>` and `</h2>`, or if you just want to match empty `<h2></h2>` occurrences. If it's the later,  `str_replace('<h2></h2>', ...` will work fine :) x

Comment: That is correct, but my question is: Can I add these patterns on one line instead of running it three times? Currently I have three lines, for example: $content = str_replace("<!--[if gte mso 9]&gt;-->", "", $content); $content = str_replace('<h2></h2>', "", $content);...

Comment: I see, yep you can. If you pass an array in you can match them all in one go: `$content = str_replace(array('<!--[if gte mso 9]&gt;-->', '&nbsp', '<h2></h2>'), '', $content);`.

Comment: Doing it in one call is slightly faster than three separate calls of `str_replace`, yes (although this probably won't have a noticeable effect on normal sized PHP scripts) x